# Angular 6 - Using channels in Rxjs Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

The following Angular 6 service can be used to send/receive messages to/from other services/components (note that `getMsg` returns an Observable):

```
@Injectable({ 
    providedIn: 'root' 
})
export class MessageService {

    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    sendMsg(message: any) {
        this.subject.next(message);
    }

    getMsg(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Now, what I need is to allow the sender/receiver to use channels, similar to AngularJS event names in $emit/broadcast. `sendMsg` signature would be as follows:

```
sendMsg(channel: string, message: any)
```

and to receive a message, the receiver will have to subscribe the Observable using a channel name. Is this possible?

Note: I don't want to use `filter` in the subscription as it would affect performance if the number of messages is large. I prefer to use an Rxjs native option.

Comment: You don't want to use `filter` because you want an RxJS option? I'm confused...

Comment: native option = named channel

Answer (score 3):

You can still use a single subject but filter out the channel that you don't want to subscribe or send, something similar to the following approach.

```
export class MessageService {

    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    sendMsg({channel,message: any}) {
        this.subject.next({channel,message});
    }

    getMsg(_channel): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable().filter(({channel,res})=>(channel==_channel));
    }
}
```

Usuage

```
messageService.send('channel1','hello').subscribe()
messageService.getMsg('channel1').subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in solution to this in rxjs. I‘d suggest to keep your current approach, but build a wrapper arround each possible channel. Here is an example:

```
export class MessageChannelWrapper {
   news: string,
   warnings: string,
   alerts: string

   constructor( ){}
}


wrapper = new MessageChannelWrapper();
wrapper.news = 'this is the news'.
```

This way you can extend your wrapper and add as much 'channels' as you need and directly access them by name.

The other solution is to add a Subject for each channel to the Service and subscribe to the channels you need.